# Colab notebook in GitHub opens to older version

Tags: github, google-colaboratory

I have a colab notebook i saved in a github repo.  I click on the "open in colab" button.  Notebook opens.  However, it opens to an older version of the colab notebook.  How do I "force" always opening the latest version when clicking the "open in colab" button on a colab notebook> Thank you.